# object property(type,format) not render while dynamically select selectbox using patchValue

Tags: angular, typescript

I tried to set the value to sort object having the value type and format. but it's not rendered. below is my code to set value using patch

```js
let arr = <FormArray>this.myForm.controls.users;
arr.controls[0].patchValue({ name: this.test[0].name, displayOrder: this.test[0].displayOrder,type:this.test[0].sort.type});
```

Below is the html code

```js
<fieldset formGroupName="sort"> 
<tr><td>type:</td><td><input type="text" formControlName="type"></td></tr>
<tr><td>format:</td><td><input type="text" formControlName="format"></td></tr>
</fieldset>
```

Below is the code URL

[Stack Blitz Code URL](https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-formgroup-current-test?file=app%2Fapp.component.ts)

Below is the json format

```js
[
  {
    "name": "manu",
    "displayOrder": 1,
    "sort": {
      "type": "first",
      "format": "normal"
    },
    "data": [
      {
        "category": "electrical",
        "name": "ele"
      }
    ]
  },
  {
    "name": "divya",
    "displayOrder": 1,
    "sort": {
      "type": "second",
      "format": "center"
    },
    "data": [
      {
        "category": "tech",
        "name": "ea_tcv"
      }
    ]
  }
]
```

Below i have attached the screen-shot, i am unable to set the value to type and format when i am selecting select box dynamically. below is the screen shot.

[image]

any body help on this to render the value dynamically into sort object(type,format) while selecting select box?
working now, but got typo error: below screen shot[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

try this

```
 const sorts = this.myForm.get(['users', 0, 'sort']) as FormGroup;

    sorts.patchValue({type : 'your_value' , format :'your_value'})
```

Comment: help me to get resolve the typo error, attached please check

Comment: I have changed FormArray to FormGroup it's wokring now.  const sorts = this.myForm.get(['users', 0, 'sort']) as FormGroup;

    sorts.patchValue({type:this.test[0].sort.type , format : this.test[0].sort.format});

Comment: Please edit your answer to below.    const sorts = this.myForm.get(['users', 0, 'sort']) as FormGroup;